# How to store an image path in the shared preferences in android?

Tags: android, image, sharedpreferences

I have got an image path that I want to store in the shared preferences.

1. How do I store the path inside the shared preferences?
2. How can I retrieve the image path from the shared preferences?

Comment: Please, make just a little effort, it's the second result from google - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: store like string and get it...

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) will help you. Pay your attention at `Editor` class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is, convert your image to it's Base64 string representation:

```
Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
realImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 

String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
textEncode.setText(encodedImage);

SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit=shre.edit();
edit.putString("image_data",encodedImage);
edit.commit();
```

and then, when retrieving, convert it back into bitmap:

```
SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String previouslyEncodedImage = shre.getString("image_data", "");

if( !previouslyEncodedImage.equalsIgnoreCase("") ){
    byte[] b = Base64.decode(previouslyEncodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
    imageConvertResult.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

However, I have to tell you that Base64 support is only recently included in API8. To target on lower API version, you need to add it first. Luckily, [this](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html) guy already have the needed tutorial.

Also i have to tell you that this is a complex procedure and shareprefrence use only to store small amount of data such as user name and password that's way you can also use such a method:

store image path (from sdcard) into Share preferences like this--

```
SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit=shre.edit();
edit.putString("imagepath","/sdcard/imh.jpeg");
edit.commit();
```

To load your image path you can use this

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
                "pref_key", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedPreference.contains("imagepath")) {
            String mFilePath = sharedPreference.getString(imagepath,
                    null);
        }
```

After getting you path you can use:

```
File imgFile = new  File(mFilePath);
if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Comment: One more question: When i retrieve the image path, how can I make that for example an image view shows that image?? How shall I implement the path to do that?

Comment: check the updated answer: if the file doesn't exist you can show message File doesn't exist!!

Answer (score 0):

Store the path as a **string**.

```
Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit();
e.putString("your_preference", your_path.toString());
e.commit();
```

This has also been asked many time before, hence the -1

Answer (score 0):

```
final SharedPreferences sPreference = getSharedPreferences(
                "pref_key", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final Editor spEditor = sPreference.edit();
        spEditor.putString("img_path", mFileName);
        spEditor.commit();
```

The above code is useful to save your image path into shared pref.
Now to retrieve the image path, Use following:

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
                "pref_key", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedPreference.contains("img_path")) {
            mFileName = sharedPreference.getString(img_path,
                    null);
        }
```