# saving and retrieving imagepath in shared preferences in android

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

my app lets user's set their profile picture either by choosing a picture from the gallery or take a picture with camera. i have been able to implement that part successfully but whenever the app resumes, the picture disappears.i am now looking for help on how to save the image path in shared preferences so that i can retrieve the image on resume. Below is what I've tried without success.

```
private void selectImage() {

    final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UsersInfo.this);
    builder.setTitle("Set a profile picture");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
            else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
            {
                Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

            }
            else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        bitmapOptions);

                viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                String path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                f.delete();
                OutputStream outFile = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {
                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor c=getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath,null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            Log.w("ImagePath", picturePath+"");
            viewImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");


    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "edition.last.cp.mobilelife.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    selectedImage = prefs.getString("picturePath", "");

    displayUserSettings();
    super.onResume();

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "edition.last.cp.mobilelife.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("ImagePath", selectedImage); // Store    selectedImagePath with key "ImagePath". This key will be then used to retrieve data.
    editor.commit();


    super.onPause();

}
```

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814551/how-to-store-an-image-path-in-the-shared-preferences-in-android) .

Answer (score 0):

create a new Class called SessionManagement

```
public class SessionManagement {

private static final String EXTRA_IMG_PATH = "img_path";  
private SharedPreferences pref;
private Editor editor;
private Context _context;

public SessionManagement(Context _context) {
    super();
    this._context = _context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(SharedPreferencesName, privateMode);
}

public boolean getPath() {
    return pref.getString(EXTRA_IMG_PATH, null);
}

public void setPath(String imagePath) {
    editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString(EXTRA_IMG_PATH, imagePath);
    editor.commit();
}

}
```

and in your activity:

```
public void savePath(String path){
  SessionManagment sm = new SessionManagment(getApplicationContext());
  sm.setImagePath(path);
  }

public String getPath(){
  SessionManagment sm = new SessionManagment(getApplicationContext());
  return sm.getImagePath(sm);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
String x = null;

SharedPreferences spPrint = getSharedPreferences  
("edition.last.cp.mobilelife.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String y = spPrint.getString("ImagePath", x);
```

Then you can set the the value of y where you want.